# how to start the gitlab pipeline?

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want host my vue page on gitlab pages.

I added the

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml file to be placed in the root of your repository

pages: # the job must be named pages
  image: node:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
    - mv public public-vue # GitLab Pages hooks on the public folder
    - mv dist public # rename the dist folder (result of npm run build)
    # optionally, you can activate gzip support with the following line:
    - find public -type f -regex '.*\.\(htm\|html\|txt\|text\|js\|css\)$' -exec gzip -f -k {} \;
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public # artifact path must be /public for GitLab Pages to pick it up
  only:
    - master
```

and

```
// vue.config.js file to be placed in the root of your repository

module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/' + process.env.CI_PROJECT_NAME + '/'
    : '/'
}
```

as described but the  pipeline is not running. are there other configuration I need to do?

Comment: Did you push on master ?

Comment: Yes I did. but nothing changed.

Comment: and if you go to `CI/CD` > `Pipelines` > `Run pipeline` and select `master` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have not enabled the pipelines to run then make sure that the pipeline specifications are in the right place. You can also manually trigger/rerun pipelines from the `Pipelines` page.

Unlike GitHub, GitLab doesn't run by default. You can check if you have enabled CI/CD by going to `Settings` > `General` from the side navigation menu then scroll down to the `Visibility, project features, permissions` section. There should be a toggle button called `CI/CD`. Please make sure this is enabled/checked, it should look like this:

[image]

Then to manually trigger or rerun pipelines please go to `CI/CD` > `Pipelines` from the side navigation menu. If you ever encounter any problem with your pipelines or wish to debug a failed pipeline this is a great place to start as it provides you with full logs of the pipeline's run time.